# privacy issue - login external website via facebook id

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Recently I had to access a page on a website via my facebook id.

Wondering, if it is possible that they can collect information such as who my friends are and so on?

Basically I got an email to check out a link.
I click on the link, It says I have to login to facebook.
I log in. I get the warning..Leaving facebook.
Then I click continue and it takes me to the site.

Is this bad programming or phishing behind the scenes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It depends what kind of information they asked for.

When they write their code, they ask for certain privileges, or permissions. You, in turn, by logging in, give them permission to do whatever they asked for.

So, in theory, it is possible that they now know who's your friend.

If you've signed in on a website that wasn't Facebook, and that simply asked for your credentials without appearing genuine, than you can bet those people will be able to steal your information and know who your friend is.

Comment: what if my profile is private by default. Like no one can see my posts nor my friends unless they are my friends

Comment: If you've given them permission to see your friends, they can see your friends, regardless of your profile.

Comment: Well this is the only warning i get:

Comment: For the safety and privacy of your Facebook account, remember to never enter your password unless you're on the real Facebook web site. Also be sure to only download software from sites you trust. To learn more about staying safe on the internet, visit Facebook's Security Page. Please also read the Wikipedia articles on malware and phishing.

Comment: Basically I got an email to check out a link.

Comment: Well, in that case, it's both possible that you signed in on some illicit website, or that you logged in on some normal website, and you gave it permission to get your email from Facebook.

Comment: ok i just updated my main question, thanks for answering me :)